# What is ${title} in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently working on a Yii project using the Wdcalendar extension. I am not great with Javascript, but have been able to achieve what I need. However I am confused about one small thing.

When a user hovers over an event they see a tooltip (simply just a title attribute of the element). The element is formed with the following piece of code:

```
<div class="rb-o ${eclass}" id="${id}" title="${title}" style="color:${color};">
```

The one thing I do not understand here is `${title}` etc. Is this something to do with Javascript? or is this waiting to be filled with a php variable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have tried searching for this on Google, but not sure what to search. If you could point me in the direction of the docs for this I will be more than happy to read this myself. I am not looking for people to do the work for me. Just a push in the right direction.

Comment: "or is this waiting to be filled with a php variable?" - you already have the right direction... PHP Manual.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their time.

Comment: By itself, it's not clear that this _is_ PHP, since those replacements won't be made outside of PHP tags (and that looks like HTML, since there is no `echo`). They could be placeholders in a templating engine (in which case they are just text), or perhaps Yii `echo`s the whole page (in which case they are indeed PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to templating, not Javascript.

The ${} indicates that the symbol inside will be replaced by a value (without ${}) before the page render the HTML.

Comment: Many Thanks for the Answer. Will accept shortly

Answer (score 1):

```
${} are called Complex (curly)
```

This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.

Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$.

[manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)